# Format of date printing it in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-formatting

The input that am giving for my javascript function is

```
`Wed Jul 30 2014 11:34:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
```

the fucntion that need to return this in to my needed fomat i.e

```
 July 30 2014 11:34 AM
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5jHqU/8/

Comment: checkout Date object methods. You can create any format according to you.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) helps you?
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)